# Does the given matrix have a square root?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, matrix-equations

Given the following matrix, I was asked to tell whether the matrix is the square of some matrix or not.

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} $$

Since this matrix is diagonal, a square root is

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & i & 0\\
0 & 0 & i
\end{pmatrix} $$
Am I right?

Comment: Right since $i^2=-1$.

Comment: The context can influence the correctness of your answer, but you're right.

Comment: One can interpret this geometrically: The original matrix is the transformation matrix of $\Bbb R^3$ defined by reflection through the $x$-axis, or just as well a rotation of $\pi$ about the $x$-axis. Thus, a real square root of the original matrix is the matrix encoding a rotation of $\pi / 2$ about the $x$-axis---this is just the rotation in Jose Carlos Santos' answer (for a certain choice of rotation direction).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right if the question was about matrices with complex coefficients, but wrong if it was about matrices with real coefficients. In the latter case, an answer would be$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: How you have calculated?

Comment: Rotation by 90° is the square root of rotation by 180°. -- Also, this is not just about complex vs. real coefficients: José's solution works for *arbitrary* fields (or even rings) of coefficients

Comment: Just a correction: rotation by 90° is a square root of rotation by 180°, not the square root.

Comment: Sorry, @HagenvonEitzen, but I  do not get it. Can I prove this that the square root is the matrix provided in the answer?

Comment: Your matrix is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos(\pi)&-\sin(\pi)\\0&\sin(\pi)&\cos(\pi)\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and you want a square root of it. All you need is $2\times2$ matrix whose square is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\cos(\pi)&-\sin(\pi)\\\sin(\pi)&\cos(\pi)\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. But the later matrix is the matrix of a rotation of $\pi$ radians. So, take a rotation of $\pi/2$ radians or a rotation of $-\pi/2$ radians.